# Modulus option quietly nerfed for Solve?

Tags: equation-solving, modular-arithmetic

Recently asked my students to put together something like this:

```
Reduce[x^2 ==b, b, Modulus -> 11]
```

For me, on 12.1, this gives:

```
{{b -> ConditionalExpression[0, x == 0]},
 {b -> ConditionalExpression[1, x == 1 || x == 10]},
 {b -> ConditionalExpression[3, x == 5 || x == 6]},
 {b -> ConditionalExpression[4, x == 2 || x == 9]},
 {b -> ConditionalExpression[5, x == 4 || x == 7]},
 {b -> ConditionalExpression[9, x == 3 || x == 8]}}
```

I liked that this helped us quickly count (and describe) squares mod $n$, and it was a nice place to brag on Mathematica for helping us solve $x^2\equiv b\pmod{n}$ for $b$ even though $b$ appears to already be "solved for."

But they are reporting, with 12.2, that they just get `{{b->x^2}}` as the output. The Wolfram Cloud does the same.

I understand, perhaps, that `Reduce` might be an alternative in some sense. Maybe it's the "right" way to solve the problem. But it doesn't have the same user-friendly sorting of solution sets by $b$ value. It also seems odd to break this functionality in an update, when `Modulus` is still supported by `Solve` as far as I can tell.

Does anyone know exactly what happened here? Or am I missing a good, easy, quick fix/work-around?

Comment: `Solve[x^2 == b, b, Modulus -> 11, MaxExtraConditions -> All]` (or `Method->Reduce`)

Comment: That's interesting. Did they change the value or behavior for default `MaxExtraConditions`?

Comment: What does nerfed mean? Turned into a foam football?

Comment: @KellenMyers - I don't have insight into WR decisions, but likely: SW has been on a "cleaner output/simpler output" push for the last few versions.

Comment: @Michael E2 presumably from a real one, yes.

Comment: In V12.2.0, I get something different: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPb2I.png

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I observe:

```
$Version
(*  "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"  *)

Reduce[x^2 == b, b, Modulus -> 11]
(*
(x == 0 && b == 0) || (x == 1 && b == 1) || (x == 2 && b == 4) ||
 (x == 3 && b == 9) || (x == 4 && b == 5) || (x == 5 &&  b == 3) ||
 (x == 6 && b == 3) || (x == 7 && b == 5) || (x == 8 && b == 9) ||
 (x == 9 && b == 4) || (x == 10 && b == 1)
*)

BoxForm`UseTextFormattingQ = True;
Solve[x^2 == b, {b}, Modulus -> 11, Method -> Reduce]
(*
{{b -> ConditionalExpression[0, x == 0]},
 {b -> ConditionalExpression[1, x == 1 || x == 10]},
 {b -> ConditionalExpression[3, x == 5 || x == 6]},
 {b -> ConditionalExpression[4, x == 2 || x == 9]},
 {b -> ConditionalExpression[5, x == 4 || x == 7]},
 {b -> ConditionalExpression[9, x == 3 || x == 8]}}
*)
```

To get just the quadratic residues, eliminate `x`:

```
Solve[x^2 == b, {b}, {x}, Modulus -> 11]
(*  {{b -> 0}, {b -> 1}, {b -> 3}, {b -> 4}, {b -> 5}, {b -> 9}}  *)
```

To get the reported response, try the following, which is at least correct:

```
Solve[x^2 == b, {b}, Modulus -> 11]
(*  {{b -> x^2}}  *)
```

I don't know why the behavior changed.  You could try reporting it to WRI.  Perhaps it wasn't intended.

Comment: I believe it was changed to avoid the `ConditionalExpression` flavor as default.